# Creating ERD Diagram From Case Study

Tags: mysql, database, relationship, erd

i am trying to create an ERD diagram for a crowdfunding service. I am not sure if i took Entities right and relationships between them.

The task is create Rules(Sentences for relationship) and Find needed Entities.

Project owners call for public participation in order to finance their innovative ideas, namely a product.
The public pre-orders a product, which is offered at an initial price.

What are the entites and relationships ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - "what can you suggest" is not a good fit for questions here.
Do you have specific questions?

Comment: Hello, sorry, did i find all necessary entities and write correct relationships between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've missed a few entities and relationships.

```
The system has many projects.
A project has exactly one owner.
A project has exactly one product.
A product has exactly one price.
A product has zero or more orders.
An order has exactly one backer.
A backer may have many orders.
An order has (?) payments.
A project has a derived attribute of "total funding", which is calculated by adding up the value all the orders (or payments?)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, what are the verb phrases between Backer and Order , Order and Product ? Also Backer can be called by only one Owner or by many owners ?

Comment: Again - this is not a "do my homework for me" service. What do _you_ think the verb phrases are?